# How do I prevent my background macros from stopping when I use Sleep?

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I run Sleep, all my background macros stop working. i want to be able to do OnKey events while having the sleep constantly running.

Here's the part with sleep API

```
Sub Bombs()
 Do While bomb.Offset(, 1).Value <> "*"
    bomb.clear
    Set bomb = bomb.Offset(, 1)
    bomb.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Sleep (200)
Loop
End Sub
```

it basically causes a red cell to move accross the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a customized sub `Wait()` that I created some years ago which I usually use in lieu of `Sleep`. See if it helps you. Here is a very basic example that I created for testing purpose.

```
Sub Bombs()
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "Sample"

    Dim bomb As Range

    Set bomb = ActiveCell

    Do While bomb.Offset(, 1).Value <> "*"
        bomb.Clear
        Set bomb = bomb.Offset(, 1)
        bomb.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Wait 5
    Loop

    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", ""
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, however I wuold like to make the timer faster than 1 second which is why i'm using sleep instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3221162: Make `ByVal nSec As Long` to `ByVal nSec As Double` and then pass `.2` for example `Wait .2`

Comment: I thought wait did not go any lower than 1 second?

Comment: @user3221162: `Wait` is just a Name that I gave for the sub. It can be any valid name.

Comment: @user3221162 [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264416%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: @user3221162: If you have anymore queries, Just leave a comment here. I will answer them when I get up. It is 3:30 AM and my bed is already missing me :)

Comment: It seems that I still can't do any OnKey events during the duration of the execution. Basically I want this to loop forever back and forth accross the screen, while I am able to move another "block" by using onKey events, Up,down,Left,right.

Comment: @user3221162: May I see your exact code so that I can test it?

Comment: You can upload your file in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: My workplace blocked those sites. I'll upload it when I get home tonight. Thank you